# Где предлагать синонимы меток?

Tags: поддержка, метки, синонимы-меток, нытьё

Собственно, не могу найти, где предлагать синонимы меток. Списки синонимов, голосование за синонимы и тому подобное - нашёл, а вот именно где предложить новый - нет.

И хорошо бы этой ссылке быть на странице c [описанием привилегии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Открываем "сводку" метки (вики-описание) ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info)):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Скроллим вниз, посматривая в правую колонку:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...и видим под списком связанных меток ссылку на страницу синонимов *"предложить cиноним метки »"* (выделена на скриншоте) ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/synonyms)).

Comment: Ой.. А я ожидал где-то на страницах со списком меток найти кнопку с выбором обеих...

Comment: Я так понимаю, надо взять описание основной метки и там нажать предложить синоним?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, именно так (интересно, куда делись уведомления о комментариях).